# Is it a way to generate karma unit test for Angular?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I used to unit test my AngularJS application using Jasmine and Karma. I would like to know if is it a way to generate dynamically karma unit test files.

By the way is it a good thing to generate (or try so) unit test files or is it preferable to do it manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to auto generate the angular unit test for components , services, pipes, directives you can use this

```
npm i ai-test-gen-angular
export OPENAI_API_KEY=somekey
node ./node_modules/ai-test-gen-angular/index.js "relative/path/to/service/or/somecomponent.component.ts" "relative/path/to/tsconfig.json"
```

You will need to have a OpenAi api key to use this Library as it uses open ai i.e. generative AI technology to create unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

`Karma` is a test runner and you can choose/mix your own test frameworks such as `Jasmine`, `mocha` etc.

Generally, you can use `karma` and `jasmine/mocha` for `unit testing`, `end-to-end testing` etc.

Manual testing is required all the time in terms of any `new features/enhancements/upgrades` etc whenever you change something and test the changed code/UI/functionality.

But the `automated testing` with karma said above are required to avoid the regression testing effort where you didn't change the code directly but there should be an indirect impact to find any of the new changes broken the existing functionality.

When you automate this karma/jasmine testing in to the `CI/CD` build tools like `TeamCity/Bamboo/Jenkins` etc, you could find the regression impact as early as possible (*most probably on the development phase*) instead of letting it to go into `UAT/Staging/Pre (or) post production` phases.

Thus to summarize,manual testing is always required to test the immediate changes and automated test cases are required to test the regression impact.

At minimum, unit testing should be required and having user acceptance testing and end-to-end testing would be best to cover.

Hope it clarifies your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I used to unit test my AngularJS application using Jasmine and Karma.

Karma is a direct product of the AngularJS team from struggling to test their own framework features with existing tools. As a result of this, they made Karma and rightly suggest it as their preferred test runner within the AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).

Jasmine is a behavior-driven development framework for testing JavaScript code that plays very well with Karma. Similar to Karma, it’s also the recommended testing framework within the AngularJS [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing). Jasmine is also dependency free and doesn’t require a DOM.

[From source: scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/testing-angularjs-with-jasmine-and-karma-part-1)

> I would like to know if is it a way to generate karma unit test files.

Which way are you talking about is unclear but, if you need to generate karma unit test files or learn unit testing, then [Adam Morgan from scotch.io](https://scotch.io/tutorials/testing-angularjs-with-jasmine-and-karma-part-1) have made a very nice tutorial about the topic.

> By the way is it a good thing to generate (or try so) unit test files or is it preferable to do it manually ?

The answer is pretty simple. Generated files are just a generic skeleton for your code, so that you have something that you don't need to write from scratch. It expects you to implement actual test flow, otherwise it will be meaningless in real world testing. I would prefer generating the basics and extend the code to fulfill my requirements than coding manually from ground zero.